# React Native cannot find Java executable, using wrong javaHome

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle

`react-native run-android` consistently fails due to an incorrect javaHome, but it's not the one defined by the environment. Where do I find this?

---

On a new create-react-app React Native project I get error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin\java.exe

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin\java.exe
```

I don't have `jdk1.8.0_162` on this machine.

the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is set to C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\openjdk-11.0.15_10` (for my user and the system) which exists and works as expected.

Similarly both the system and user variables include `C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\openjdk-11.0.15_10` in their respective `Path` env variables. No setting points at a jdk1.8.0_162 directory.

So far as I can tell `gradlew.bat` get the java path from `JAVA_HOME`. Where is it getting `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162` from?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get past this by:

- Opening the `android` directory in Android Studio
- Open setting **Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle**
- **Gradle Projects** section
- Open the **Gradle JDK** drop-down and select 'Add JDK' nagivating to the correct one.

In *android studio* click retry on the blue failed gradle build bar and let it do its thing.

Once it's finished running `npx react-native run-android` worked as expected.

nb. Android Studio crashed a lot between these steps.

---

Still have no idea what causes it.